# Clone a block of HTML and append it to another div

Tags: jquery

I have 3 different variations of "append" going on from different demos because I was trying to get anything to work, but none of them appear to be doing anything at all. I know the jQuery works because `remove()` on the original element works just fine when I uncomment it out.

Can you tell me what I'm missing here? Can you also tell me which variation I should be using/what the difference is?

Here's where I'm building: [Stable Demo](http://gne.95f.myftpupload.com/work-2/)

**The jQuery (on demo site)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".simplefilter").clone().appendTo($(".filtering-wrap")); // doesn't work
    $(".simplefilter").clone().append($(".filtering-wrap")); // doesn't work either
    $(".simplefilter").clone().appendTo(".filtering-wrap"); // also doesn't work
    $(".simplefilter").remove(); // This does work when enabled     

});
```

**The Filter Code to Clone (on demo site)**

```
<ul class="simplefilter simplefilter_3985">
  <li class="active" data-filter="all">all</li>
  <li data-filter="1">Stores</li>
  <li data-filter="2">Creative</li>
  <li data-filter="3">Amazon</li>
</ul>
```

**The AppendTo Container**

```
<div class="filtering-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: 1) Where is the `.simplefilter` element? 2) You don't need to 2 document.ready event handlers 3) Your `.appendTo(".filtering-wrap")` *should* work, if everything has been set up correctly 4) `remove()` will be removing it immediately after appending, so you may need to comment that line

Comment: My assumption is the user is expecting the `remove()` to not be affecting the cloned elements just inserted, which would not be the case.

Comment: That is true, I do not want to remove them both. I have the remove() commented out right now because I thought that might be removing both elements, but alas - it still doesn't clone over. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Simple filter is within the demo - I can copy over what's being output and edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the elements, append their clone to the destination, and then remove them.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $filters = $('.simplefilter');
  
  $filters.clone().appendTo('.filtering-wrap');
  $filters.remove();
});
```

```css
.filtering-wrap {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtering-wrap"></div>

<div class="simplefilter">Filter 1</div>
<div class="simplefilter">Filter 2</div>
<div class="simplefilter">Filter 3</div>
```

But really, if you are going to remove them, just move them and do not clone.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.simplefilter').appendTo('.filtering-wrap');
});
```

```css
.filtering-wrap {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtering-wrap"></div>

<div class="simplefilter">Filter 1</div>
<div class="simplefilter">Filter 2</div>
<div class="simplefilter">Filter 3</div>
```

Elements can only have one parent at a time, so attempting to append an element that already exists in the DOM will cause jQuery to move them, not create a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I will take this answer and keep it in my toolbox.